# i am not able to insert values in mysql table for vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

 Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection   
 Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.BrandsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StoreDataSet.brands)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=brands"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "insert into database.brands(id,name,,created_at,updated_at) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "')"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader

            MessageBox.Show("Data saved")
            MysqlConn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `Query = "insert into database.brands(id,name,,created_at,updated_at) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "')" ` error is after the name there are two unwanted commas.

Comment: yeah i had tried , but still not wrkng

Comment: POst the ERROR ! If id is Foreign Key  you must remove:  '" & TextBox1.Text & "',

Comment: adn delete a comma: "insert into database.brands(id,name,,created after NAME !